# Is a way to calculate faster x of this congruence

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

We have $20x \equiv 49 \ (mod \ 23)$

and I noticed after multiplying $20*22$ or increasing $49$ by $23$ to $440$  emoticon:|. Is there a faster way to calculate x?

Solution $x$ is $22$

**Notice I  must calculated this by hand**

Comment: Well, $20\equiv -3$ and $49\equiv 3$ so $x\equiv -1$.

Comment: ah instead of reduce by 'one number' 23 in case 20 and reduce few times in case 49 I increased 49 by 23 to 440...

Comment: Am I think correclty it is little tricky?

Comment: Not sure I get what you are asking.  I don't understand your method, but you got the right answer!  After all, $22\equiv -1\pmod {23}$ we our results match.  I think my method is easier, but yours appears to have worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}
20x &\equiv 49 &\pmod{23} \\
-3x &\equiv 3 &\pmod{23} \\
x &\equiv -1 &\pmod{23} \\
&\equiv 22 &\pmod{23}
\end{align*}

Comment: Cancelling $-3$ is valid because $-3$ is coprime to $23$ so invertible (by Bezout).

Comment: Yes. Please note @BillDubuque 's comment.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case, of course it is easiest to notice that $20\equiv -3$ and $49 \equiv +3$, as in the comments.

In the general case, it is useful to first apply Euclid's algorithm on the multiplier of $x$ (here, $23$ and the modulus.  So let's say we needed to solve $23x=2\pmod {79}$; we would have
$$
79 = 3(23)+10\\23 = 2(10)+3\\10=3(3)+1
$$
and then
$$
1 = 10 - 3(3) = 10-3(23-2(10))\\
= 7(10)-3(23) = 7(79-3(23))-3(23) \\= 7(79) - 24(23) \equiv -24(23)
$$
So $$24(23) \equiv -1 \pmod{79}$$
and $x = 24(-2) \equiv 31 \pmod{79}$.